# Broken links to review queues on close/reopen privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link

https://security.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions

There are links to the [close votes](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/close-votes) and [reopen votes](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/reopen-votes) queues (below "Reviewing close and reopen votes"), but they 404. The correct links should be:

close votes: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/close
reopen votes: https://security.stackexchange.com/review/reopen

Comment: This is true on all sites.

Comment: I went and fixed it on [Meta's page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions), does that propagate through the network somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki entry on Meta that was used as template for the rest of the network was using the wrong links.

I missed this when checking the wiki entries for updates to push to the rest of the sites.

The [update by Ben](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171684/broken-links-to-review-queues-on-close-reopen-privileges-page#comment508540_171684) has now been taken and all other sites will be updated on the next build with the now correct links.